# variable not able to store data Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, frontend, jsonparser

I'm trying to parse JSON object but it's showing weird behaviour. when i try to save the following, unexpected console is coming.

```
var abc = '[{"id": 2,"result": "MwLYo\x5C/Awp=="}]'
console.log(JSON.parse(abc))
```

The value of "result" key is not coming as expected. how to fix this code as I want to send exact value to the API.

Comment: You are currently parsing a JSON array of objects. Arrays in JSON are defined by `[]`. Simply remove the preceding and succeeding square brackets. Otherwise, you could use `JSON.parse(abc)[0]` to access the first array element.

Comment: @Joery, can't it will be array of objects. So need solution for this only. 
And JSON.parse itself is not working. you can try yourself

Answer (score 1):

```
var abc = '[{"id": 2,"result": "MwLYo\x5C/Awp=="}]'
console.log(JSON.parse(abc))
```

result

[image]

What you are doing is correct. but when you parse "MwLYo\x5C/Awp==" you will get  "MwLYo/Awp==". 3 characters after \ are missing

"\" is an escape character so char coming after "\" will be automatically removed by JS. you need to avoid "\" on your string

And another solution is to replace every "backslash" with a forwardslash
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note, `\x5c` is a ascii char for `\`. Hence it gets converted while printing in console. Check: https://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html

Answer (score 1):

`\` is an escape character in JavaScript, when your code is parsed `\x5C` is parsed as an ascii code and omitted.

Normally you can just use `\\` to avoid this, but because the string is parsed first by JavaScript and then again by `JSON.parse`,

You can instead use the unicode character for `\`, (`\u005C`) and [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw).

```js
let abc = String.raw`[{"id": 2,"result": "MwLYo\u005Cx5C/Awp=="}]`;

console.log(JSON.parse(abc)[0].result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `\x5C` as an ascii character, so it gets converted to its utf-8 value, which is `\`.

```js
const jsonString = '[{"id": 2,"result": "MwLYo\x5C/Awp=="}]'
console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString));
```

I noticed because my regex to match escape characters wasn't working.

`(No \ before) ( \ ) (no \ after)`

`(?<!\\)(\\)(?!\\)`

Comment: No, JSON can be start with '{' or '['